# Any way to "play to" tv from ubuntu (not a media server)

Tags: sound, video, remote, media

Like the title says... i'm looking for a way to play music/videos from my media player TO a Tv on the same network. Basically like you can do with windoze media player and have been able to do for a while... surely Linux can do something the same or better?

I'm not looking to install a media server then use the TV to browse the media server and find files, which I have done already and the media browser on the TV is a bit frustrating when you have many files.

Comment: What sort of TV? Are you talking about sending video to a DLNA endpoint (something that some smart TVs are)?

Comment: yes, its a samsung smart TV. it can connect to dlna servers and play that way but browsing media on the tv itself is quite bad. in windoze media player there is a "play to" option that finds the tv on the network so i can find what i want to play on the pc and just send it to the tv.

Comment: Good question - apparently there are some 'smart tvs' that work as a client to view videos on your 'server' computer software? However there are few if any articles on the cheaper common hdmi dongles that allow Androids and laptops to share screen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a DLNA server (like [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/)) on the host, import media, etc. I *thought* MT had its own "play to" functionality through its webui but it's been years since I last played with it.

If it does, that's your whole solution there. If it doesn't you'll need a controller.

If you're looking for control *from* a computer, [GUPnP-AV Control Point](https://live.gnome.org/GUPnP/) is a fair bet but control point software is widely available for all sorts of devices, eg: [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en).

Comment: that GUPnP-AV Control Point looks pretty cool :P going to play around with that one for a bit. only had a brief look at mediatomb but will give that one another look over and see whats possible.

Comment: @Luckdragon If you don't get on with MediaTomb (I had problems with some transcoding), MiniDLNA worked well for me but that really is a very Spartan sharing tool. For that to work you will need a remote (or to browse from the TV).

Comment: For me, MiniDLNA failed with most videos (e.g. avi/divx). Serviio somehow works (see [minidlna and samsung tv file format doesn't support](http://askubuntu.com/q/313275/68291) for details). But still, I'd like to have a possibility to "beam my screen" to the TV (e.g. show what's in the browser, or some presentation, etc.), like if it was another "cloned screen".

Comment: After installing MediaTomb from Ubuntu 12.04 repos, I get (with the Chrome browser) MediaTome UI disabled: check configuration. I've checked MediaTomb's support forum and there are no answers to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also not sure if I should be using MediaTomb. I want to view an flv file (though I can convert it to mp4 if necessary) on my new Sony TV which I can see on my home network, it's connected to my router by ethernet as device MT8520-1 with an IP address allocated by my router. I've looked up Sony's manuals on their web site and they give no info about using the ethernet connection.

Comment: MediaTomb worked directly after setting it and adding videos on my samsung TV!